# How to implement cascade insert with MEAN/MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm trying to implement cascade insert for objects with 1 to many relationship in Mongoose/MongoDB and struggling to implement it. In this case, university has one to many relationship with departments. Here is my university object.

```js
var UniversitySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  departments: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Department'
  }]
});

mongoose.model('University', UniversitySchema);
```

Here is my department schema:

```js
var DepartmentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  University: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'University'
  }]
});

mongoose.model('Department', DepartmentSchema);
```

Here is what I tried putting inside post in the schema. Basically when I save a department, I'm trying to insert department Id in the university to establish one to many relationship in both direction. Of course, I'm also saving university ID while creating department - which is pretty easy.

```js
DepartmentSchema.post('save', function(next) {
    var university = University.find({_id: this.university._id});
    if(!university.departments) {
     university.departments = []; 
    }
    university.departments.push(new ObjectId(this._id));
    university.save().exec();
    next();
});
```

This gives error on this line, saying it can't recognize save method on university object.

```js
university.save().exec();
```

I've also tried doing this inside model server controller, but that doesn't seem right as most methods are wrapped by REST request. Of course, I can handle this from client side by making multiple requests, but I suppose there is a way to do this on server side. Since this is very internal to data layer, in my opinion, I should be able to handle this using mongo middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of queries get passed to callbacks, not returned.

```
var university = University.findOne({_id: this.university._id});
```

The variable `university` is now a query object, not the result of the query. This is why you get `TypeError: Object# < Query > has no method 'save'`. Results from queries are passed to the callback function of the query:

```
University.findOne({_id: this.university._id}, function(err, university){

    // here is your result
});
```

Similarly, you need to pass the final callback into your save:

```
university.save(next)
```

Comment: Now I've put inside callback and also using callback for save, but I still get error on university.save

`DepartmentSchema.post('save', function(next) {

  University.find({
    _id: this.university._id
  }, function(err, university) {

    if (!university.departments) {
      university.departments = [];
    }
    university.departments.push(new ObjectId(this._id));
    university.save(function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log('err-->' + err);
      // saved!
    });
  });

});`

`
   university.save(function(err) {
              ^
TypeError: Object  has no method 'save'
`

Answer (score 1):

The save method must have the callback function parameter, try this:

```
university.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
})
```